# Botão com linha dupla no texto

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer um botão que tenha 2 linhas pré separadas para o texto.

Por exemplo:

```
<button>
   <span>cima</span>
   <span>baixo</span>
</button>
```

Ele me daria algo tipo:

[image: bt]

---

*Não precisa ser dessa forma o código, só foi um exemplo teórico.*

Comment: Pq não usa div que eh um elemento bloco e já quebra a linha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a quebra de linha através da tag `<br>`. O código ficaria assim:

```
<button>
    cima
    <br>
    baixo
</button>
```

Comment: Mesma resposta no SOen, basicamente essa é uma das soluções que mais usam
Mas também é possível utilizar o width pra limitar o tamanho e quebrar a linha e outras nº maneiras também :)
Resposta do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469088/html-can-i-display-button-text-in-multiple-lines

Comment: Iago, sempre poste as referências que buscou, caso tenha. Assim, enriquece o conteúdo da resposta e também dá crédito ao outro.